# How does one select a server group to push on save on pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

I find that I created another server group then it stops pushing on save. Does anyone know how to fix this? The options tab doesn't really show an option nor anything else.

[This page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uploading-and-downloading-files.html#autoupload_definitions) wasn't very helpful:

> ##### Configure automatic upload of changed files to the default server or server group
>
> PyCharm considers a local file changed as soon as it is saved either
> automatically or manually (**File | Save All** or `⌘ S`), see [Work
> with source code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-source-code.html). Changed files can be automatically uploaded only
> to the default deployment server.
>
> 1. Open the Options dialog by doing one of the following:
>
>    - From the main menu, choose **Tools | Deployment | Options**.
>    - In the **Settings** dialog (`⌘ ,`), go to **Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment | Options**.
> 2. From the **Upload changed files automatically to the default server** list, choose when you want PyCharm to upload changed files:
>
>    - To upload any manually or automatically saved file, choose **Always**.
>    - To upload only manually saved files, choose **On explicit save action**.
>    - To suppress automatic upload, choose **Never**.
> 3. If you enabled automatic upload, optionally configure the scope it should apply to:
>
>    - Select **Skip external changes** to exclude local changes that were made using a third-party tool (a VCS, a script, and so on) from
>      automatic upload.
>    - Select **Delete remote files when local are deleted** to have PyCharm automatically delete remote files during automatic uploads in
>      case the local ones are deleted.
>
>      Note that this option serves as an extra safety measure and may result in unwanted files remaining on the remote server. As an
>      example, consider a local file Foo.php, which is renamed to Bar.php.
>      Since renaming a file is technically indistinguishable from deleting
>      the file and creating a new one, the following will happen after
>      automatic upload:
>
>      - If the option is enabled, the remote server will only contain Bar.php.
>      - If the option is disabled, the remote server will contain both Foo.php and Bar.php after automatic upload. You will probably
>        need to delete Foo.php manually afterwards.
>
> > Enabling the **Upload changed files automatically to the default
> > server** option also enables Upload to default server in **Settings |
> > Tools | Actions on Save**.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your new server group is the *default server group*. For that go to deployment then right click on the server group you want to make default, then make sure automatic save is on.

If it works you will see something like this:

```
[3/14/23, 12:05 PM] Automatic upload
[3/14/23, 12:05 PM] Upload file '/Users/brandomiranda/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_experiment_analysis_sl_vs_maml_performance_comp_distance.py' to '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_experiment_analysis_sl_vs_maml_performance_comp_distance.py'
[3/14/23, 12:05 PM] Automatic upload completed in 39 ms: 1 file transferred (1.8 Mbit/s)
```